# Why my python program is showing tracebacks and raise WaitTimeOut error when I am running my project" voicy -a desktop assisstant"?

Tags: audio, timeout, speech-recognition

LINE OF CODE:
audio = r.listen(source, timeout=3) ........LINE 72

query = takeCommand().lower()..............LINE 92

RESULT:
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\MyCode> python voicy.py
Listning...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\MyCode\voicy.py", line 92, in 
query = takeCommand().lower()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\OneDrive\Desktop\MyCode\voicy.py", line 72, in takeCommand
audio = r.listen(source, timeout=3)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_*init*_.py", line 489, in listen
raise WaitTimeoutError("listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start")
speech_recognition.exceptions.WaitTimeoutError: listening timed out while waiting for phrase to start

Comment: I don't know why but I'd recommend formatting your code

Comment: Hi, pleaase read help on [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)